# Unable to resolve jar dependency in Java project for

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 java projects on GitHub, the first project produces a java library and the second project uses it.

The first project is build via first job in yaml file and it installs the library in /home/runner/.m2/repository/ successfully

Then when the second project is build via the second job in the same yaml file , it fails with error

```
Failed to execute goal on project <>: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project Could not find artifact <>:jar:1.0-
SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

In my second project, I have included the dependency to load this library jar(produced by first project) from the repository.

MY understanding is that my second project should load the jar library from the /home/runner/.m2/repository/ but its not loading it.

Any help is appreciated.

Also can we access /home/runner/.m2/repository/ to check if it contains the library jar.

```
./project_account_library/account_library => Contains maven project 
./project_account_service/account_service => Contains maven project 
./.github/workflows/build.yml
```

Here is the yml file

```
name: Build account service
on:
push:
branches: [main]

env:
IMAGE_NAME: accountservice

jobs:


build_dependency: 
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
permissions:
  packages: write
  contents: read

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
    distribution: 'temurin' # See 'Supported distributions' for available options
    java-version: '17'
  

- name: Build Dependency
  run: |
      cd ./project_account_library/account_library
      mvn clean install
      

build_accountservice: 
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
permissions:
  packages: write
  contents: read


steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
    distribution: 'temurin' # See 'Supported distributions' for available options
    java-version: '17'

- name: Build Account Service
  run: |
      cd ./project_account_service/account_service
      mvn clean install
```

First Step

```
[INFO] Installing /home/runner/work/<>/<>/target/account_
library_1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to 
/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/<>/<>/account_library/1.0-
SNAPSHOT/account_library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Second Step

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal on project <>: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project <>: Could not find artifact com.<>. 
<>:account_library:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks Frennky

I now used only 1 job and below is my new .yml file
- name: Build Account Service
run: |
cd ./project_account_library/account_library
mvn clean install
cd ../../project_account_service/account_service
mvn clean install

First directory is successfully built but it fails to  cd to ../../project_account_service/account_service and fails to build with below error

/home/runner/work/_temp/ea229141-b0c3-455d-82f0-12ff588d420a.sh: line 12: cd ../../project_account_service/account_service: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you share your yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're missing dependencies on your second job is because those 2 jobs, by default, run in parallel and they do so on 2 different runners. From [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#the-components-of-github-actions):

> Each job will run inside its own virtual machine runner, or inside a
> container...

There's few ways you can go around this. I can suggest one quick and easy, and another that would probably be a way to go, but require slightly more effort.

- Easy way out of this is to put all steps in a single job.
- Better way would be to make use of Github Package repository, where
  you could push your lib/dependencies and then resolve them for your
  service.

For more details on Github Package repository you can check [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry).

**Update:**

Ok, I've reread your new error and I think I understand the issue.

If I got it right your dir structure is as follows:

- repo

  - project_account_library

    - account_library
  - project_account_service

    - account_service

Each run step actually starts at root of you repo. You can use `working-directory` like so:

```
# ...
- name: Build Dependency
  run: mvn clean install
  working-directory: ./project_account_library/account_library
# ...
- name: Build Account Service
  run: mvn clean install
  working-directory: ./project_account_service/account_service
```

Comment: Thanks Frennky, I used only 1 job now but cannot switch between the project folders. I added the details in my original post.

Comment: Quality question needs to be focused and detailed. With my first comment I've guided you to provide more details, now I need to point out that the question loses focus if we we start tackling path issue here. If you don't manage to figure this out on your own, it would be best if you open a new question.

Comment: However, I can give you few pointers how to debug and resolve it. There is no way to `ssh` to runners unless they are self-hosted. You can add self-hosted runner to any org/repo. Once you `ssh` to self-hosted runner, it should be much easier to debug path issues. If you can't bring up self-hosted runner, you can use `pwd` and `ls` within `run` command to figure out where you are. Also, you can use `working-directory` for `run` command to specify in which dir you want to execute `mvn`.

Comment: Thanks Frennky, i followed your suggestions & now  able to build both the projects.